# Delete data of file

Tags: file, fortran, fortran77

I need to open a file which I don't know if it exists each time I perform the open operation. If it exists I want to open it and store the information inside it into an array, do some calculations, clean the opened file and write the new information to it. If it doesn't exist I want to leave it open to write information to it.

I have to use fortran 77.

My code is:

```
 OPEN(7, FILE = "C:/Abaqus_JOBS/mELF.txt", 
1 action = "READ", status = "UNKNOWN")
```

My problem concerns `status = "UNKNOWN"`, if the file exists I need to clean it (delete all data). How can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with the `inquire` statement:

```
logical :: file_exists
! ...

inquire(file='filename.txt',exist=file_exists)
if ( file_exists ) then
  ! Do stuff
else
  ! Do other stuff
endif
```

Or, since you are going to wipe the file anyway, just open it with `status='replace'` ;-) The difference between `'unknown'` and `'replace'` is, that `'replace'` will create a new file will if it doesn't exist.

For FORTRAN 77, `status='replace'` does not exist. Then, the `open` statement could read:

```
open(1234, file='filename.txt', status='unknown', iostat=ierr)
if ( ierr .eq. 0) then
c    file opened successfully, delete 
  close(1234, status='delete')
endif

c Open a new file
open(1234, file='filename.txt', status='new', iostat=ierr)
```

Comment: Thanks. I think "status=Unknown" will also do the trick. My quetsion know concerns how to delete all data in a file so that I can write new information to it? Thanks again

Comment: I don't think `status='replace'` is available in fortran 77. Am I wrong? Thanks

Comment: Note, too, that `status=replace` will delete the (contents of the) file when the `open` statement executes.

Comment: Ah I see.. Well, then you should use `'iostat=ierr'`. If the file could not be opened, then `ierr` will be non-zero!